# Can't install mean.io Stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, npm, mean-stack

I'm trying to install the `Mean` stack by issuing `sudo npm install -g mean-cli` command. but I get the following error every time I try :

```
\
> mean-cli@0.10.12 preinstall /usr/lib/node_modules/mean-cli
> node ./scripts/preinstall

npm WARN deprecated json-file-plus@2.0.0: Before v3.0.0, errors in fs.writeFile would not be propagated

> mean-health@0.1.7 postinstall /usr/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/node_modules/mean-health
> node ./postinstall.js
```

I have updated `json-file-plus` to **@3.0.0**. Also I'm using **ubuntu 14.4.2 64bit**

Comment: Do you still get the same message after updating the json-file-plus package?

Comment: @TempOrary, Yes I am